# Is $f(x)=x\sin x$ uniformly continuous in the interval $(0,a)$ when $a>0$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

Is $f(x)=x\sin x$ uniformly continuous in the interval $(0,a)$ while $a>0$?

I have proven that its not uniformly continuous in the interval $[0,\infty)$ because the function "$x\sin x$" is continuous in general but its doesn't converge to any final limit. so its not uniformly continuous in the interval $[0,\infty)$ but what about the interval $(0,a)$ while $a>0$? any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't proven anything.

Comment: $x\sin x$ is continuous on $[0, a]$.

Comment: I mean I proved this in a previous follow up question that I solved on paper. "I didn't write it here" because I didn't think it will be relevant to the question itself. I thought mentioning that fact would help.

Comment: @John its $(0,a)$ an open interval. and if u meant the same thing, then can u explain why  ?

Comment: $x\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, a]$, so it is uniformly continuous on $(0, a)$.

Comment: @john we can say that only because its not a closed interval according to the definition to uniform continuity?

Comment: Any continuous function is uniformly continuous over a (relatively) compact interval.

Comment: The fact that the function does not converge to any final limit does not imply that it is not uniformly continuous on the interval $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: "Doesn't converge to any final limit" is misleading - for example $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous but doesn't converge to any value as $x\to \infty$

Comment: While this explains why OPs partly solution is wrong, it dosen't actually answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\sin x$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,a]$, and is therefore uniformly continuous on that interval. Since $(0,a)$ is a subset of $[0,a]$, then $x\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on the open interval $(0,a)$